# Is it possible to get a link to a private telegram channel?

Tags: telethon, aiogram

I am interested in the following question: is it possible to extract a link to a private channel if I am a member of it, but do not have administrator rights? I can extract id, title and @username for public channels, and only id, title for private ones. Maybe you can somehow interact with system messages? Since when I send a private channel to the bot to receive information about it, the system message “You sent CHANNELTEST to the BOTEST bot” comes into the chat with the bot, where CHANNELTEST is the title in which the link to this channel is hidden and maybe it can be extracted somehow? I will welcome any ideas and appreciate any help.

So far the code looks like this:

```
async def get_channel_info(username_title, client):
    try:
        channel = await client.get_entity(username_title)
        title = channel.title
        username = channel.username

        if not channel.username and channel.broadcast:
            return title, None
        else:
            link = f't.me/{username}'
            return title, link

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None, None


@dp.message(F.chat)
async def handle_request_chat(msg: Message):
    chat_info: int = msg.chat_shared.chat_id

    title, channel_link = await get_channel_info(chat_info, client)
```

I tried using this method, but it didn't work:

```
async def get_exported_invites(client, chatlist):
    result = await client(functions.chatlists.GetExportedInvitesRequest(chatlist=chatlist))
```